# difficulty with .closest ,parent, next functions in jquery

Tags: jquery

So im trying to use the .closest function and been having problems so i went with something else but this left me stumped so trying to figure it out.

this is the html:

```
 <div class="faqW">
        <div class="faqQues2"> the question goes here </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="faqAns2"> answere to faq question here.</div>
    </div><!-- faq wrap ender -->
```

this is the CSS hiding the answer(will change to js to hide after im done)

```
.faqAns2{
    background-color:#CC6;
    color:black;
        display:none;
}
```

this is the jq im **trying** to use:

```
var question = $('.faqQues');
var answer = $('.faqAns');
var question2= $('.faqQues2');
```

(varying tries with no results)

try 1 :

```
question2.click( function(){
    $(this).parent().next('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500); 
});
```

or

```
question2.click( function(){
    $(this).parent('.faqW').next('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500);  
});
```

try 2:

```
    question2.click( function(){
    $('.faqW',$(this)).closest('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500);    
});
```

try 3:

```
    question2.click( function(){
$(this).next('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500);  
});
```

Ive tried numerous ways, including rearanging the html for .parent etc, but to no avail.

What im wanting is that, when the question is clicked, that the closest answer is toggle displayed.

I cant figure out what im doing wrong.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It seems you first have to learn about [the relationship of DOM nodes](http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/09/20/relationship-in-the-dom/). Then it will become clearer what the methods are actually doing. If you don't know in which direction they traverse, then you are just blindly trying. The second step is to read the documentation of the methods carefully. For example, `.next` selects the next sibling *if and only if* it matches the selector, not the next sibling which matches the selector. That said, there are millions of question here in the spirit of "get next element with class X".

Answer (score 1):

'.closest(selector)' goes up the ancestor chain and finds the first ancestor that matches the selector.

`.next(selector)` looks at the next element and returns the very next element only if it matches the selector.  It does NOT look for the next element that matches the selector regardless of how far away it is.  It only returns something if the very next element matches the selector.

From a question, to get the next answer in the save div, you could do this:

```
.nextAll('.faqAns2')
```

nextAll will get all siblings that match the selector that are after the element in the jQuery object.

For your specific problem, I think this will work:

```
question2.click( function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500); 
});
```

Or, if you make your HTML more generic, you can use the same jQuery for all questions and answers:

```
<div class="faqW">
    <div class="faqQues"> the question goes here </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="faqAns"> answere to faq question here.</div>
</div><!-- faq wrap ender -->
```

And jQuery:

```
$('.faqQues').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.faqAns').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Since each Q&A pair is confined in it's own div, you can also do this:

```
$('.faqQues').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.faqW').find('.faqAns').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two next calls since next will return only the immediate next sibling, that matches the selector if given. Here, the answer div is one DOM node after the question.

```
question2.click( function(){
    $(this).next().next('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500);  
});​
```

Take a more closer look at the DOM traversal functions http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1):

If you traverse to the parent, the `.next()` matches the immediate sibling of the element.

To search the children of `.faqW` you can use `.find()`, or to search for the next answer from `.faqQues2` you can use `nextAll()` which doesn't only search immediate sibling, but gets all of the matched siblings.

**$.find() - http://jsfiddle.net/urLqE/:**

```
question2.click( function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500); 
});
```

​

**$.nextAll() - http://jsfiddle.net/urLqE/1/:**

```
question2.click( function(){
    $(this).nextAll('.faqAns2').slideToggle(500); 
});
```